# Resolve company name / TLD to industry?

Tags: data-request, usa, business, internet, companies

Where can I find a comprehensive data set of U.S. companies with their respective *industries* and internet top level domains (TLDs), if any?

Such as the [Fortune 500](http://fortune.com/fortune500/) list...

```
Company Name    Website Industry
Ford Motor  http://www.ford.com Manufacturing
JetBlue Airways http://www.jetblue.com  Travel, Recreation, and Leisure
Bank of America http://www.bankofamerica.com    Financial Services
Northwestern Mutual http://www.northwesternmutual.com   Financial Services
...
```

... but much larger, including small/medium businesses?

Comment: The company I work for specifically solves this problem... check out datafox.com

Answer (score 2):

[DUNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Universal_Numbering_System) is the best business list that I can think of -- but I have no idea if it has industry info in it.  Years ago, when you wanted an SSL certificate, registrars wanted your DUNS number to verify you weren't mascarading as another company.  Unfortunately, it's not an open list.

For something that's more likely to be free, for the U.S., there's a the [EIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Employer_identification_number), which the government uses to track employers.  I'm not aware of any searchable list, though.   The [SBA's website](http://www.sba.gov/community/blogs/community-blogs/business-law-advisor/how-do-i-find-ein-0)   points to the [SEC's EDGAR](http://www.sec.gov/edgar/searchedgar/webusers.htm) for public companies, and [GuideStar](http://www.guidestar.org) for non-profits.  This would miss private companies, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid this is generally the kind of data which is not centrally collected by a government agency, and not freely given by businesses that set up to collect it for their own use or for sale to third-parties.

That said, NASDAQ has [a list of companies by industry](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?industry=ALL) that is 6500+ entries (not limited to the NASDAQ exchange).  I'm not really sure how they select the industries, but they aren't exactly labels from the [official NAICS list](http://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/sssd/naics/naicsrch?chart=2012).

You can download the list as a CSV, but the downloaded list does not include a URL for the company. The HTML version does, if you were inclined to write a scraper.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't taken an extensive look yet, but you might have some success with [opencorporates](http://opencorporates.com).

Answer (score 0):

I know you're posting in the OpenData SE but here are some other places to look in addition to SEC's EDGAR and GuideStar some of which have APIs

- Lead gen services like salesgenie.com
- LinkedIn
- YellowPages